# How to get Raw html from string in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3, html-encode

I have `&lt;label class='ash'&gt;Comment Removed&lt;/label&gt;` in the database.

When I show this on the grid. I get this on the page:

```
<label class='ash'>Removed</label>
```

Actually I should just get Removed in Gray color

How can I convert this to Html like I do in MVC 3 Razor view?

```
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(comment.txt)) works fine
```

I am using jquery 1.6 on MVC 3

I tried:

```
$("<label class='ash'>Comment Removed</label>").html()
   unescape($(txt)).html()
```

May be it is simple, but can't figure it out

Comment: [This solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/javascript-jquery-html-encoding) might help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should do the trick for you:

```
var elemString = $('<div/>').html("&lt;label class='ash'&gt;Comment Removed&lt;/label&gt;").text();
```

[Here's a demo showing it being appended to the body ->](http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/dwCPN/)

If you need to do this multiple times, you could simplify with a function, like so:

```
function DecodeHtml(str) {
    return $('<div/>').html(str).text();
}

var encodedStr = "&lt;label class='ash'&gt;Comment Removed&lt;/label&gt;";
$('body').append(DecodeHtml(encodedStr));
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery :

```
var YuorHtml = "<p>Some Text  <em>Some Text</em> <strong>Some Text</strong></p>";
  
 $('#YuorID').html(YuorHtml)
```